# How to re-export all types from module?

Tags: typescript

I want to re-export all types in a module. Is there a way to achieve this?

I did try:

```
export type * from 'react-router-dom';
```

But it doesn't work:

> Only named exports may use 'export type'. ts(1383)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typescript 5.0 now has [support](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52217) for this:

```js
export type * from "external-module"

//OR

export type * as ns from "external-module".
```

Update typescript and you’ll be able to!

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to import the type as Types then export it like this way.

```
// your-module
import type * as Types from "external-module";
export { Types };

// Usage by the end user
import { Types } from "your-module";
let a:Types.Class;
```

hope it's helpful.